# override Backbone's Collection-fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web

I want to get my collection in a NON-RESTful way, so I decide to override the `Collection.fetch` with

```
App.carClc = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : App.cardModel,
    url : 'http://localhost/bbtest/data.php',
    fetch : function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : this.url,
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I don't know how to set my collection to the response. I'm new to BackboneJS, thanks all of you!

Comment: i dont get it. why write a own $.ajax ? the fetch do it without your code the same way!?!? ..

Comment: the server-side's style is not RESTful

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you want to add a custom "decorator" to `fetch`, but not override it completely, try:

```
    var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        //custom methods

        fetch: function(options) {

            //do specific pre-processing 

            //Call Backbone's fetch
            return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        }

  });
```

Here, you don't have to roll out your own `$.ajax`

Also, don't forget the `return` in the last line if you want to use the jQuery promise returned by Backbone's `fetch` method.

See http://japhr.blogspot.in/2011/10/overriding-url-and-fetch-in-backbonejs.html for more details.

Comment: This answer feels much more clean to me, and allows you to not limit yourself from any other features .fetch() has that you might want to use later on.

Comment: @JRM Can you please expand?

Comment: shouldn't this be 'apply' instead of 'call', since arguments is technically an array?

Comment: @ifightcrime `options` is an object, not an array. So shouldn't `call` be used instead?

Comment: whoops you got it sorry. I was browsing too fast and wasn't paying attention. They way I usually do it is just apply arguments `Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);`

Answer (score 30):

Backbone collection has two methods to set new data add and reset. Let's say you want to replace all collection data with the incoming data and therefor use the reset:

```
 App.carClc = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model : App.cardModel,
url : 'http://localhost/bbtest/data.php',
fetch : function() {
    // store reference for this collection
    var collection = this;
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : this.url,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            // set collection data (assuming you have retrieved a json object)
            collection.reset(data)
        }
    });
}
})
```

Comment: collection.reset(data), searched for hours

Answer (score 3):

I am using something like this:

```
$.when( $.ajax( URL, { dataType: "json" } ) )
    .then( $.proxy( function( response ) {
            ctx.view.collection.reset( response );                              
    },ctx ) );
```

The main point beeing I use `collection.reset(data)` to reinitialize the collection

Comment: Just a nitpicking point. Isn't $.ajax a promise, and therefore the code above can be re-stated outside of $.when(), i.e.: $.ajax(...).then(...), should work fine? Nice work on the collection, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to keep fetch "thenable" for promises then you could also do something like this:

```
fetch: function() {
    var self = this,
        deferred = new $.Deferred();

    $.get(this.url).done(function(data) {
            // parse data
        self.reset({parsed data});
        deferred.resolve(); //pass in anything you want in promise
     });
     return deferred.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this for every model and/or collection, override `Backbone.ajax`.

Overriding `Backbone.ajax` gives you the request `options` that would be normally passed to `$.ajax`.  You only need to return the response of `$.ajax` (or some other `Promise`) and don't need to worry about setting stuff in the collection/model.