# Overrriding collection fetch() method in Backbone.js is causing a double request to the server

Tags: backbone.js

I'm doing an application with Backbone.js and Require.js. I have an "Opportunities" Backbone collection and I needed to modify the fetch method because the data from the server comes inside a "results" object.

I did the trick by doing something I found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14301442/923323), at this point all looks good.

The problem is that I noticed that the fetch method is asking the server for the data TWO TIMES and not ONE as expected.

I am testing and now I found that if I remove this code: `return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);` Backbone asks the url for the data only one time, obviously this code is causing the problem but I don't know the reason.

This is my Backbone collection

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'models/Opportunity'
], function(Backbone, Opportunity){

    var Opportunities = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        url: "/api/v1/opps/",

        model: Opportunity,

        // Need to have custom fetch because json data is coming inside a
        // "results" array inside the JSON.
        fetch : function(options) {
            // store reference for this collection
            var collection = this;
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : this.url,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    // set collection main data
                    collection.reset(data.results);
                }
            });

            // For some reason this is causing a double request
            // to the server
            return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        }
    });

    return Opportunities;

});
```

Someone knows the reason because this error is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fetching it twice because you're using jQuery to fetch it directly, the calling the models own fetch method which will call an AJAX request as well.

If you want to return `data.results` back to your collection (and subsequently models), you can use the [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method, like:

```
var Opportunities = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/api/v1/opps/",
    model: Opportunity,
    parse: function(data){
        return data.results;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this solution and you are totally right, this method is the way that I needed, did the trick!